# jquery ajax json help

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Hello I have a PHP method which is called using `$.ajax()` the end result is the I return something similar to `json_encode($insert)`, on success of the ajax call being successful I alert the return data and get the following,

`{"content":"Helle this is a testasdasdasdsd","retrain":false,"created_at":1296247015,"employers_id":"4"}`

I then try to narrow down the data that I show by doing this `html.content` however this returns as undefined when I alert, below is my code

Javascript:

```
$('#employer_feed').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/employer/feed',
        data: $('#employer_feed').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(html) {
            alert(html);
            $('#feed').append('<div class="feed_item">'+html.content+'</div>');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
if($this->f->insert($insert)) {
                if(is_ajax()) {
                    echo json_encode($insert);
                }
            }
```

This is what the $insert looks like,

`Array
(
    [content] => Helle this is a testasdasdasdsd
    [retrain] => 
    [created_at] => 1296247448
    [employers_id] => 4
)`

Comment: can you show us what $insert looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `dataType: "json"` to your `$.ajax` call. Also, you may want to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` from the PHP side.